# Getting all keys & their values from nested objects in JSON array (w/out jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json

JSON newb asking: Given the following json data:

```
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "userName": "Herbie",
            "dates & times": [
                { "2014.08.01": "120.0" },
                { "2014.08.02": "123.0" },
                { "2014.08.03": "126.0" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userName": "Wayne",
            "dates & times": [
                { "2014.08.01": "120.0" },
                { "2014.08.02": "123.0" },
                { "2014.08.03": "126.0" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userName": "Freddie",
            "dates & times": [
                { "2014.08.01": "120.0" },
                { "2014.08.02": "123.0" },
                { "2014.08.03": "126.0" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userName": "Ron",
            "dates & times": [
                { "2014.08.01": "120.0" },
                { "2014.08.02": "123.0" },
                { "2014.08.03": "126.0" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "userName": "Tony",
            "dates & times": [
                { "2014.08.01": "120.0" },
                { "2014.08.02": "123.0" },
                { "2014.08.03": "126.0" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

... and wanting to retrieve a specified user's dates & times data so it can be rendered, e.g.:

```
Date 01: Time 01
Date 02: Time 02
Date 03: Time 03
```

I've read much about looping thru arrays and objects but I'm still confused as to how to get the dates & times (or any keys/values) if the keys are unique. So far I have this:

```
var usersArray = myObj["Users"];
for (var user in usersArray){
    if (!usersArray[user].userName == selUser) {
        alert("user not found");
    }
    else if (usersArray[user].userName == selUser) {
        var datesAndTimesArray = usersArray[user]["dates & times"];
        console.log(selUser +"'s dates & times: " + datesAndTimesArray); // returns array of objects
    }
}

for (var someKey in datesAndTimesArray){
    // here's where I'm struggling, trying to get all the dates & times for the selected user, such that I can render it as described above
    // pseudo-code
}
```

Btw: studying javascript, not using jquery etc.

Many thanks in advance,

svs

Comment: Just get rid of the `alert`. If you're looking for `Freddie`, you'll alert "user not found" when the loop looks at Herbie and Wayne before him. And use `break` when you find the user you want.

Comment: Also, use a `for` loop to loop arrays, not a `for..in`.

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` loops for iterating through arrays in JavaScript. Use a plain `for` loop and an index variable to explicitly count through the properties, or else use the `.forEach()` method.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you but actually I am getting the selected user :) problem I'm trying to solve is getting all of the data in all of the (date & time) objects for the sel user. Thanks for the tip to use break.

Comment: If the keys are really unique, `date & time` should be a single object, not an array of objects with one property each. Then `for (var someKey in datesAndTimesArray){` would work just fine.

Comment: Yes, you're getting the selected user, but you're also getting a bunch of alerts before that, aren't you? Actually, I guess not, because you wrote `!usersArray[user].username == selUser` instead of `usersArray[user].username != selUser`. Your test will never be true.

Comment: @Pointy Use a for loop and not for/in loop - for the inner loop, I assume? Thanks for that lesson! In any case if the dates are unique, then how do I iterate all without an index?

Comment: I mean instead of `for (var user in usersArray)` do `for (var user = 0; user < usersArray.length; user++)`

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you Felix, I think this is the core issue - that my json structure is not entirely appropriate, at least not with the current state of my comprehension of for loops. (In a prev version of this data I was able to get what I wanted but then there wasn't a Users array.) Anyway, do you mean:     "dates & times": {
     "2014.08.01": "120.0" ,
     "2014.08.02": "123.0" ,
     "2014.08.03": "126.0"
    } ? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `datesAndTimesArray` is an array of objects, you need a nested loop to process it.

```
for (var i in datesAndTimesArray) {
    var obj = datesAndTimesArray[i];
    for (var date in obj) {
        console.log('Date ' + date + ': Time' + obj[date]);
    }
}
```

It would probably be better for the dates and times to be single objects instead of arrays, e.g.

```
        "dates & times": {
            "2014.08.01": "120.0",
            "2014.08.02": "123.0",
            "2014.08.03": "126.0"
        }
```

Then you only need to do `for (date in datesAndTimesArray)`

Comment: Thanks again. You and Felix have confirmed my suspicion as to how I'm formatting my data (ergo the "JSON newb asking", and having formatted it more than a few ways already). Also I appreciate the heads-up on my if statement; I was a little doubtful of that too but it was back-burnered since it wasn't preventing me from working on getting the data ;)

Comment: p.s. using if (usersArray[user].userName != selUser) {
 alert("user not found"); } as you sugg above, I'm getting error for all selections

Comment: That's what I said would happen, which is why you shouldn't do that test.

Comment: if you want to know if the user isn't found, check at the end of the loop to see if `datesAndTimesArray` is set.